# Syncing Telegram contacts without phone/API

Tags: telegram, telegram-api, import-contacts

Short: is there a way to let Telegram Windows sync my contacts that I'm storing on my computer in xls/vcf/csv format?

Long: I need to let Telegram Windows (or web) access a xls/vcf/csv-formatted file, that is saved on my local computer, where my contacts are stored. I tried to find a Telegram Windows version/software/platform that has this capability but unfortunately all versions assume you have already uploaded your contacts through your phone or via importing them via API, neither of I which I want to use.

Since Telegram is an open source, I would imagine that implementing a contacts-syncing-capable Windows- (or web-) based software is doable (?). However, before I start implementing one, I thought I would ask in case anyone is aware of an existing one that already has this feature.

Comment: You can write a code for doing this using `telethon`. Beware that Telegram limits the number of contacts you can import in a short period.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it limits the number of contacts you can "import". But does it also limit the number you can "sync" as well? That is, is "importing" and "syncing through the phone" (and not through Windows, if it were possible) recognized by telegram servers as the same action? What if I cross that limit then delete all my contacts, will I be able to sync them all again without that limit? Or once I'm capped then I'm limited forever?

Comment: Last time I tested this was 4 years ago. By then, there was an initial limit of 2500 contact, and then 100 new contacts every day. 100 new contacts a day means 36500 contacts a year. The limits might have changed now.

Deleting contacts doesn't reset the limit. OS platform doesn't matter either.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, did you test it using "contact syncing" via phone app? or using coding via API?

Comment: via code, but doesn't matter at all. the limit is enforced by the server regardless of the client.